# Can I use additional fields in TypeOrm many-to-many join table

Tags: many-to-many, entity, typeorm

I have two tables: Painting and Exhibit with tables painting and exhibit whose many-to-many relationships are handled by the exhibit_paintings table - id, paintingId, exhibitId.

Because paintings can have a price unique to an exhibit, I want to use an extra field -  exhibitpaintingprice - in the exhibit_painting table. How do I access that field on a nextjs page?

How should I change this otherwise successful code?

These two lines will produce a collection of paintings, without the exhibitpaintingprice.

```
  const exhibitRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Exhibit);
  const exhibit = await exhibitRepository.findOne({
    where: { id: exhibitid },
    relations: ["gallery", "paintings"],
  });
  return exhibit;
}
```

table body that mapped the collection :

```
                  <>
                    {exhibit.paintings ? (
                      exhibit.paintings.map((painting) => {
                        const exhibitpainting = painting.exhibitRelations;

                        return (
                          <tr key={painting.id}>
                            <td>{painting.id}</td>
                            <td>
                              <Image
                                src={painting.picture}
                                alt={painting.title}
                                width={100}
                                height={100}
                              />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <Link href={`/painting?id=${painting.id}`}>
                                {painting.title}
                              </Link>
                            </td>
                            <td>{painting.description}</td>
                            <td>Exhibit note</td>
                            <td>{painting.media}</td>
                            <td>
                              {painting.height}h x {painting.width}w x .5d
                            </td>
                            <td>{painting.price}</td>
**<td>ExhibitPaintingPrice: {??????????????}</td>**
                          </tr>
                        );
                      })
                    ) : (
                      <tr>
                        <td colSpan={7}>No paintings</td>
                      </tr>
                    )}
                  </>
```

I tried

```
                            <td>
                              {painting.exhibitRelations?.exhibitpaintingprice}
                            </td>
```

generated this error: - error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'joinColumns')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a separate table by yourself instead of relying on join table provided by TypeORM.

Create another entity `ExhibitPaintings` and add two primary columns for each id. And then add ManyToOne decorators to each table and specify the join columns as those primary columns that you just created.
And then your many-to-many table is ready. Now, you can add any custom column to this table, and can query with either QuerySelector or simply via EntityManager.
Here is the GitHub discussion that would you help you. https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2402

Comment: I think you. are right. except I am totally confused about the manytoone decorators. I have three entities with tables and one junction table. junction table: exhibit_paintings , Painting/painting , Exhibit/exhibit , ExhibitPaintingDetail/ exhibitpaintingdetail this last table has foreign keys to painting and exhibit. Do I put the ManyToOne decorators in the Painting and Exhibit tables? or in the ExhibitPaintingDetail table?

Comment: In the Exhibit table, you would have OneToMany, and inside ExhibitPaintaing table, you would have ManyToOne

Comment: `@OneToOne(() => ExhibitPaintings, (exhibitPaintings) => exhibitPaintings.id)
  exhibitPaintings: ExhibitPaintings; ` 
ExhibitPaintings is the junction table created by TypeORM. I created an entity in my project in an effort to extend it.
  `@ManyToOne((type) => Exhibit, (exhibit) => exhibit.exhibitPaintingDetails)
  exhibit: Exhibit; ` 
  
  `@ManyToOne((type) => Painting, (painting) => painting.exhibitPaintingDetails)
  painting: Painting;`     This is the ExhibitPaintingDetail entity

Comment: and... the ManyToOne is generating this error: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Exhibit' before initialization for this line:  `@ManyToOne((type) => Exhibit, (exhibit) => exhibit.exhibitPaintingDetails)   exhibit: Exhibit; `

Comment: This postgres query using those three tables succeeds:     `SELECT * FROM Exhibit as e 
JOIN ExhibitPaintingDetail as epd ON epd.exhibitId = e.id
JOIN Painting as p ON epd.paintingId = p.id
WHERE e.id = 23`

Comment: This breaks.  ` const exhibit = await exhibitRepository.findOne({
     |                                        ^
  40 |   where: { id: exhibitid },
  41 |   relations: ["gallery", "paintings", "exhibitpaintingdetail"],
  42 | });`  EntityPropertyNotFoundError: Property "exhibitpaintingdetail" was not found in "Exhibit".   This is the entity relation: `  @OneToMany(
    () => ExhibitPaintingDetail,
    (exhibitPaintingDetail) => exhibitPaintingDetail.exhibitId
  )
  exhibitPaintingDetails: ExhibitPaintingDetail[];`

Comment: The ERD for the database is here: https://4l3c78.axshare.com/#g=1&p=data Relations have been defined by foreign keys except for the typeorm-generated exhibit_paintings table

Comment: delete exhibit_paintings typeorm generated table

Comment: Also, use `Relation` from typeorm when including inside entity columns.

Comment: I don't understand this last: "use Relation from typeorm when including inside entity columns".  a. what is an "inside entity column"?

Comment: When you import an entity, use it like this ‘exhibit: Realtion<Exhibit>’.

Comment: What I meant by entity column is a property inside a entity class which is also a column in database.

Comment: A type referenced in a decorated signature must be imported with 'import type' or a namespace import when 'isolatedModules' and 'emitDecoratorMetadata' are enabled. This error is coming up here:     @OneToOne(
    (type) => Exhibit,
    (exhibit) => exhibit.exhibitPaintingDetails
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: "exhibitid" })
  exhibit: Relation<Exhibit>;

  @OneToOne(
    (type) => Painting,
    (painting) => painting.exhibitPaintingDetails
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: "paintingid" })
  painting: Relation<Painting>;

Comment: This and a mirror of it in the Exhibit  entity is breaking the entity side of my code.      @OneToMany(
     () => ExhibitPaintingDetail,
     (exhibitPaintingDetail) => exhibitPaintingDetail.paintingid
   )
   exhibitPaintingDetails: ExhibitPaintingDetail[];  What is the correct syntax for the OneToMany?